# using setState inside the callback of another setState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When using useState hooks in React I have a scenario in which I would like to use it like so:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const [page, setPage] = useState(0);

setCount(currentCount => {
  if (currentCount > 0) {
    setPage(0);
    return 0;
  }
  return currentCount + 1;
});
```

Is it considered bad practice to use them nested like this? If so, are there any documentation on why this would be bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the count to `undefined` in the outer callback: you are not using the return keyword, and functions which exit without a returned value return `undefined` in JavaScript. In the inner invocation of the state setter, you are closing around the value of `currentCount` from the outer callback, and creating an expression which evaluates to `1` greater than that value.

This is potentially a bug, for two reasons:

1. `undefined` will cause a problem for any code in your program which relies on a `number` type for the state
2. [State updates may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), so it is not guaranteed that  the outer callback will finish execution either before or after the inner invocation of the state setter.

Instead this pattern will provide deterministic behavior:

```js
setCount(currentCount => {
  const useZero = currentCount > 0;
  if (useZero) setPage(0);
  return useZero ? 0 : currentCount + 1;
});
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when editing the sample code. Please take a look again.

Comment: @Mark I also updated my answer to include an idiomatic alternative while you edited your question.

Comment: for posterity: the idiomatic alternative is equivalent to the updated code in the question

Answer (score -3):

Try something like this:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const [page, setPage] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  if (count > 0) {
    setPage(0);
    setCount(0);
  }
}, [count]);
```